# detect jquery version use on or live

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a plugin which can be used in any website where I dont know the exact version of jquery and getting a few issues with the `.on()` method.

To fix it I have something simple like this but still getting errors in jQuery 1.4.2.

```
var $myElements = $('.elements'),
    myFunction = function(e){
        console.log('here');
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }

if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') {
    if(jQuery.fn.jquery < 1.4){
        $myElements.live('click', myFunction);
    } else {
        $(document).on('click', $myElements, myFunction);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't try and accommodate all versions of jQuery. What if they're using Zepto? Bundle your own version and namespace it so you can be guaranteed functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the previous answer, you can do this too:

```
;(function($) {
  if(!$.fn.on) {
    $.fn.on = $.fn.live;
  }
}(window.jQuery || window.Zepto));
```

Then you can use `on` in the rest of your code.

Comment: Much smoother answer. I'll remove mine :).

Comment: The syntax for live is not the same for `.on` so if I passed an event delegation parameter this would fail. Just one of the hundreds of caveats of this approach

Comment: This won't work. You can try selecting `$(document)` always, if `on` is not available.

Comment: @RGraham Yep, you are right. Ignore my answer. Use one of the techniques mentioned here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

You should bundle your own version of jQuery to save yourself a lot of hassle and a lot of redundant code. You can do this using noConflict to ensure that both your code and the code of the source website act independently:

```
<!-- load your jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var yourjQueryVersion = $.noConflict(true);
(function($) {
    // Now you can use $ just like you normally would
    // And it will only execute against jquery-1.11.0
    $(function() {
        var $myElements = $('.elements'),
            myFunction = function(e){
            console.log('here');
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
        $(document).on('click', $myElements, myFunction); // Yay!
    });
})(yourjQueryVersion);
</script>
```

This means that:

- You don't need to write extra code for all jQuery version differences
- If the target website upgrades to jQuery 2.0 (or similar), none of your code will break.
- The source website might even be using a CDN, so there is a good chance only one copy of the jQuery library may be loaded due to caching.